# Issue is repo creation script

Tags: bash, shell

I'm facing issue for below script. Syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is “.repo”). Intention of the script is to check whether MariaDB.repo is present or not, if not then create an empty file withe same name. Kindly suggest where i'm getting wrong & how to fix this.

```
MDB=$(find '/etc/yum.repos.d/' -maxdepth 1 -name  "MariaDB.repo")

if [[ $"MDB" -eq "MariaDB.repo" ]]
then
    echo "Repo already exists"
else
    touch /etc/yum.repos.d/MariaDB.repo
fi
```

Comment: Why don't you just check `if [ -f /etc/yum.repos.d/MariaDB.repo ]` ?

Comment: Even better, you can always do `touch /etc/yum.repos.d/MariaDB.repo` which will just update the timestamp of the file if it's already there.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems:

1. `$"MDB"` should be `"$MDB"`.
2. The output of `find` will be the full pathname, not just the basename of the file.
3. `-eq` is for comparing numbers. To compare strings you must use `=`.

But you don't need to use `find`. There's a built-in operator to test if a file exists.

```
MDB=/etc/yum.repos.d/MariaDB.repo
if [[ -f "$MDB" ]]
then
    echo "Repo already exists"
else
    touch "$MDB"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. @Barmar